# A function definition for directed acyclic graphs

Tags: algorithm, graph, vertex, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort

Let's consider the following problem: For a directed acyclic graph `G = (V,E)` we define the function "levels" for each vertex u, as `l(u)` such that:
**1.** l(u)>=0 for every u
**2.** If there is a path from u to v (u -> v) then l(u)>l(v)
**3.** For each vertex u,  l(u) is the minimum integer that satisfies both conditions 1 and 2.

The problem says:
**a.** Prove that for every DAG the above function is uniquely defined, i.e. it's the only function that satisfies conditions 1,2 and 3.
**b.** Find an `O(|V| + |E|)` algorithm that calculates this function for every vertex.

Here is a possible algorithm based on *topological sort*:
First we find the transpose of G which is `G^T`, defined as `G^T = (V,E^T)`, where `E^T={(u,v): (v,u) is in E}` which takes `O(|V|+|E|)` in total if based on adjacency list implementation: 
`(O(|V|)` for allocation and `sum for all v in V of |Adj[v]| = O(|E|))`. Topological sort takes `Theta(|V|+|E|)` since it includes a BFS and `|V|` insertions in list each of which take `O(1)`.

```
TRANSPOSE(G){
    Allocate |V| list pointers for G^T i.e. (Adj'[])
    for(i = 1, i <= |V|, i++){
        for every vertex v in Adj[i]{
            add vertex i to Adj'[v]
        }
    }
}
L = TopSort(G)
```

Comment: Let's ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a. Prove that for every DAG the above function is uniquely defined, i.e. it's the only function that satisfies conditions 1,2 and 3.

Maybe I am missing something, but this seems really obvious to me: if you define it as the minimum that satisfies those conditions, how can there be more than one?

> b. Find an O(|V| + |E|) algorithm that calculates this function for every vertex.

I think your topological sort idea is correct (note that a topological sort **is** a BFS), but it should be performed on the transposed graph (reverse the direction of every edge). Then the first values in the topological sort get 0, the next get 1 etc. For example, for the transposed graph:

```
1   2   3
*-->*-->*
        ^
*-------|
1
```

I have numbered the nodes with their positions in the topological sort. You number the nodes by implementing the topological sort using a BFS. When you extract a node from your FIFO queue, you subtract 1 from the indegree of all of its reachable nodes. When that indegree becomes 0 you insert the node it became 0 for in the queue and you number it as exracted_node + 1. In my example, the nodes numbered 1 start with indegree 0. Then, the bottom-most 1 subtract one from the indegree of the node labeled 3, but that indegree will be 1, not zero, so we don't insert it in the queue. We insert 2 however because its indegree will become 0.

**Pseudocode**:

```
G = G^t
Q = a FIFO queue
push all nodes with indegree 0 in Q
set l(v) = 0 for all nodes with indegree 0
indegree(v) = how many edges are going into node v
while not Q.Empty():
  x = Q.Pop()
  for all nodes v reachable from x:
    if indegree[v] > 0:
      indegree[v] = indegree[v] - 1
      if indegree[v] == 0:
        Q.Push(v)
        l[v] = l[x] + 1
```

You can also do it with a DFS that computes the value of each node once the recursion returns, as:

```
value(v) = 1 + max{value(c), c a child of v}
```

Note that the DFS is not dont on the transposed graph, because we'll let the recursion handle the traversal in topological sort order.

Comment: I may miss something, but how do you number the nodes like this? A topological sort only gives you nodes in a sorted order. How do you see that two nodes have number 1 in your example (should be 0 btw)?

Comment: @IVlad Can you check the algorithm I posted above based on your suggestion of DFS? Is that what you suggested?

Comment: @md5 - you number the nodes by implementing the topological sort using a BFS. When you extract a node from your FIFO queue, you subtract 1 from the indegree of all of its reachable nodes. When that indegree becomes 0 you insert the node it became 0 for in the queue and you number it as `exracted_node + 1`. In my example, the nodes numbered 1 start with indegree 0. Then, the bottom-most 1 subtract one from the indegree of the node labeled 3, but that indegree will be 1 not zero, so we don't insert it in the queue. We insert 2 however because its indegree will become 0. Added this to the answer.

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis - I find your implementation needlessly complex. Also, it's not what I meant. You don't run the DFS on the transposed graph, but on the original graph. The recursion will take care of computing values in topological sort order.

Comment: @IVlad: So it looks like more complex than the DFS method (and btw it's shorter and more common to implement topological sort with a DFS).

Comment: @IVlad OK, I corrected the algorithm until the point of topological sort but I am still confused. For example, do I have to number the nodes during the topological sort or after it and how can I do this? Also, how do I compute indegree? You would really help me understand your thinking  if you could post some pseudocode of your solution.

Comment: @md5 - I wouldn't say it's more complex. And I call "citation needed" for your statement that DFS is more common or even shorter for topological sort. I find BFS more natural due to the fact that it already traverses nodes in almost topological sort order, there's just one condition you need to use. For DFS, you have to understand recursion pretty well to understand how it can perform a topological sort.

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis - I have added pseudocode for the BFS variant. I think DFS is actually more complex because it requires calling the function for multiple nodes, but I'll add that too if you want.

Comment: @IVlad So, If I understand correctly you transpose G and then you execute a topological sort calculating indegree at the same time. But you only initialize l(v) and you don't use it at all after that.

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis - oops! I forgot the most important line :). Added it now.

Comment: @IVlad First, I think that this is not BFS. 1st, you push all nodes with indegree == 0 in the queue, but BFS pushes only one node, the starting node, in the queue. 2nd, you check indegree value in line 3 of your code but you actually calculate it for each node later (in line 5). 3rd, in the for loop when examining a child v of x you don't check if it's already discovered. I think you should use white, grey and black colors in BFS to distinguish the kinds of nodes. Can you check the implementation of BFS [here](http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.884/spring10/labs/lab4.pdf) ?

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis - (1) it is BFS. If you have more source nodes (and you do here), you have to push more. If you like it more, add another node connected to all nodes with indegree 0 and then only push that one. (2) line 3 computes indegrees to find the nodes with indegree 0. In line 5, these values are changed while the algorithm runs so you know when to push more nodes. (3) I've added code to check for already discovered nodes. Why would you need 3 colors? visited or not is a boolean state. You can check by using the indegree actually. Note that the graph is acyclic and directed.

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis - I suggest you try to understand the logic behind the algorithm rather than getting hung up on whether or not it matches a book's implementation. Run it by hand on a few example to get a feel for how it works.

Comment: @IVlad Just to clarify two more points: 1st: You run the whole indegree algorithm two times, i.e. in lines 3 and 5. Is that correct? By the way, this algorithm takes O(|V|+|E|), right? I mention this because it's a requirement of the problem. 2nd The "numbering" you are talking about in your post is actually the last line l[v] = l[x] + 1. Is that correct?

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis - (1) no, it's only run once on line 3. Line 5 just defines what indegree means... Yes, it's `O(|V| + |E|)`. (2) Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71478/discussion-between-konstantinos-konstantinidis-and-ivlad).

Comment: @IVlad Can you please check the example I posted on chat? Basically, I tried to execute the algorithm on a simple graph with 4 vertices.

Comment: @KonstantinosKonstantinidis I can't tonight, but I'll check tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have a topological sort of `G`. Then you can consider vertices in reversed order: if you have a `u -> v` edge, then `v` comes before `u` in ordering.

If you loop on the nodes with this order, then let `l(u) = 0` if there is no outgoing edges and `l(u) = 1 + max(l(v), for each v such that there is an edge (u, v))`. This is optimal and give you an `O(|V| + |E|)` algorithm to solve this problem.

Proof is left as an exercise. :D

Comment: Why take the max if you're doing a topological sort? `u` will only be reached from the node with maximum value anyway.

Comment: @IVlad The maximum is taken over the `l`-values of successor nodes according to the original edge orientation in `G`. The reversal only applies to the order in which nodes are visited. In fact the method computes a topological order on the graph derived from `G` By reversing all edge orientations.